# Swift 2 IBAction and Segue

Tags: ios, swift2

How to print 1111111 => 22222 => 333333333 of below code?
Can anyone tell me why the IBAction is not the first, but prepareForSegue is?

A.swift

```
 @IBAction func ButtonTOClassB(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("1111111")
    }



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showingB" {
       print("22222")
}
```

B.swift

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("333333333")
}
```

Console:

```
22222
1111111
333333333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your IBAction method perform segue programmatically

```
@IBAction func showLocation(sender: AnyObject) 
{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_name_here" sender:sender];

   print("1111111")
}
```

In Storyboard you need to define custom segue name = **segue_name_here**

[image]

Comment: So what thing need to do in prepareForSegue ? Is `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue_name_here" {
       print("22222")
}`

Comment: @kingyau yes!! you just got it perfect :) then if you click on button you will get desired results

Answer (score 2):

Interface Builder adds a segue action to the button with addTarget. Then your action is added after that. As the actions are called in the same order as they were added, prepareForSegue gets called first. If you wish your action to be called first you should perform the segue programmatically as RDC instructs or just not use a segue, but push the view controller programmatically.

```
@IBAction func showLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
    let bvc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB") as! B

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bvc, animated: true)
}
```